# How to add windward reports java engine in a spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, windward

I have added the below dependency in my pom.xml with profiles mentioned. but it doesn't download the jar file in maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.windward</groupId>
            <artifactId>WindwardReports</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.35.1</version>
</dependency>

<profiles>
        <profile>
        <id>windward-profile</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>windward-maven-repo</id>
                <name>windward-maven-repo-release</name>
                <url>http://maven-repository.windward.net/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate these profiles through maven project properties. and after that it will add all the required jars to the maven libraries.